# Get TextSettings.Font.Style property with GetObjectProp using Delphi Tokyo 10.2

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm using Delphi's GetObjectProp function to get the properties of the form components, I get all the properties of several components, but I can not get the TextSettings.Font.Style (Bold, Italic, ...) property of components like TLabel for example. I need to know if the component text is bold or italic. The procedure I am working on trying to get these properties follows below:

```
procedure Tfrm1.aoClicarComponente(Sender: TObject);
var
  TextSettings: TTextSettings;
  Fonte: TFont;
  Estilo: TFontStyle;
  Componente_cc: TControl; 
begin
Componente_cc := TControl(Label1);
if IsPublishedProp(Componente_cc, 'TextSettings') then
    begin
      TextSettings := GetObjectProp(Componente_cc, 'TextSettings') as TTextSettings;
        if Assigned(TextSettings) then
           Fonte := GetObjectProp(TextSettings, 'Font') as TFont;
        if Assigned(Fonte) then
           Estilo := GetObjectProp(Fonte, 'Style') as TFontStyle; // <-- error in this line 
        if Assigned(Estilo) then
           Edit1.text := GetPropValue(Estilo, 'fsBold', true);
    end
end;
```

The error displayed on the line where I marked above is.

> [dcc64 Error] uPrincipal.pas(1350): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the example I simplified the code for better understanding, but in the actual application it is more complex, with components created at runtime and can be of any Class, so I'm using rtti. I changed it to its TFontStyles segestao but the error remains.

Comment: `Style` is of `TFontStyles` type and it's not an object type but set of type property. And `fsBold` is not a property but a possible member of that set.

Comment: But how do I get the property if it is not a object type?

Comment: Use `GetOrdProp`. Set is just an ordinal value that you can query for members by `in` operator. Or if you want to print out the set members as string, you can use `GetSetProp`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`GetObjectProp(Fonte, 'Style')` will not work since `Style` is not an object-based property to begin with, it is a `Set`-based property. And `GetPropValue(Estilo, 'fsBold', true)` is just plain wrong (not that you would get far enough to call it anyway), because `fsBold` is not a property, it is a member of the `TFontStyle` enum.  To retreive the `Style` property value, you would have to use `GetOrdProp(Fonte, 'Style')`, `GetSetProp(Fonte, 'Style')`, or `GetPropValue(Fonte, 'Style')` instead (as an `integer`, `string`, or `variant`, respectively).

That being said, once you have retrieved the `TextSettings` object, you don't need to use RTTI at all to access its `Font.Style` property, just access the property directly.

Try this instead:

```
procedure Tfrm1.aoClicarComponente(Sender: TObject);
var
  Componente_cc: TControl;
  TextSettings: TTextSettings;
begin
  Componente_cc := ...;
  if IsPublishedProp(Componente_cc, 'TextSettings') then
  begin
    TextSettings := GetObjectProp(Componente_cc, 'TextSettings') as TTextSettings;
    Edit1.Text := BoolToStr(TFontStyle.fsBold in TextSettings.Font.Style, true);
  end;
end;
```

A better (and preferred) solution is to not use RTTI at all.  FMX classes that have a `TextSettings` property also implement the [`ITextSettings`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Graphics.ITextSettings) interface for exactly this situation, eg:

```
procedure Tfrm1.aoClicarComponente(Sender: TObject);
var
  Componente_cc: TControl;
  Settings: ITextSettings;
begin
  Componente_cc := ...;
  if Supports(Componente_cc, ITextSettings, Settings) then
  begin
    Edit1.Text := BoolToStr(TFontStyle.fsBold in Settings.TextSettings.Font.Style, true);
  end;
end;
```

Read Embarcadero's documentation for more details:

[Setting Text Parameters in FireMonkey](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Setting_Text_Parameters_in_FireMonkey)

Comment: Thank you, I'm going to see the doc on the pier. The example code that you provided displays the error [dcc64 Error] uPrincipal.pas (1343): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'fsBold'

Comment: @Juliano: that is because FMX uses [scoped enums](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Scoped_Enumerations). Use `TFontStyle.fsBold` instead